# GPS coordinates to pixel

Tags: java, gps

I need to create image (polygon) from GPS coordinates. I have coordinates like this:

> (49.274633220,17.160206083),(49.276968797,17.162732143),(49.278188519,17.162391767),(49.279761626,17.161087954), ......

And I need to transform them to XY pixel points. Each pair of coordinates are vertex of created polygon.

File with all coordinates:

### [GPS.txt](http://jirka.webarchitects.cz/GPS.txt)

and how the created polygon should look like:
[image: http://jirka.webarchitects.cz/polygon.png]

Any idea how can I transform the coordinates? Thanks for all reply.

Comment: You need to define a transformation to convert your spherical coordinates into (planar) x and y.  Have you a preference?  Assuming this is homework, does it specify a transformation?

Comment: I think I haven't define a transformation. In my assignment is:
_Application read from text file GPS.txt polygon of region. Each pair of coordinates is vertex on border of region._

Comment: OK, but you still need to project your sphere down to a plane somehow. There is no right answer here, just many many possible projections. See for example the [Mercator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercator_projection) projection, a fairly standard worldwide one.

Comment: I know, but I have no idea how I convert this. But thanks, I explore yours link :)

Answer (score 1):

In all cases you need a transformation form lat,lon (spherical)  to cartesian (x,y) coordinated. 
If the polygon is not bigger than 100km you can use a simple Cyclindrical Equidistant Projection.
Otherwise, you may use a Mercator Projection. (Google Maps uses that too)

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the assignment says to create a graphic?  Or is it just to read the text file and extract the pairs of coordinates?  Because you can't create a graphic without defining a transformation.  I would start by finding the max and min latitude and longitude values (making sure which is which!).  Then just use a linear scale for the longitude so that your minimum longitude goes to `px=0` and the maximum longitude goes to however wide you want your image to be.  Then do the same for latitude - it'll look distorted but at least you'll see something to start with.

By the way, the graphic you pasted doesn't seem to correspond to the coordinates you gave.  If it helps, yours look more like [this red area](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File%3aOlomoucky_kraj.svg).

Comment: Thanks for reply. The image, which I post is wrong, your "red area" is the right. 
And to your idea. It is good one, but I need to transform 12 polygon, which creates Czech Republic. Final picture, which I must draw is Czech Republic divided to a 12 regions. So linear scale will be really long work.

Comment: I don't understand "really long work". You loop over the points, find the maxs and mins.  Loop again, and do a simple interpolation `px = (lon - minlon) / (maxlon - minlon) * imagewidth` for each point.  Is that really long work?  If you have 12 polygons, get the min and max longitude for all 12 polygons first.