# Drawing polygons on right position

Tags: java, graphics

this question is continue of [GPS coordinates to pixel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15882368/gps-coordinates-to-pixel).
I need to draw a several polygons. I can draw each polygon alone, but cant all polygons on right position.

I load information about polygon from this file:
[GPS](http://jirka.webarchitects.cz/kraje_cr.txt)

I have class Kraj, which represent each polygon.

```
public class Kraj {

    String name;
    Point2D.Double points[];
    Point2D.Double transPoints[];

    Point2D.Double max;
    Point2D.Double min;

    // polygon
    Path2D.Double polygon;

    ArrayList<Kraj> kraje;

    public Kraj(String name, Point2D.Double body[])
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.body = Arrays.copyOf(body, body.length);
        // calculate a bounding box
        zjistiLimity();
        this.transPoints = new Point2D.Double[points.length];
    }

    private void transformToWindow(int width, int height) 
    {
        // convert to window
        double convertX = width / (max.x - min.x);
        double convertY = height / (max.y - min.y);

        // calculate polygon to fit in window with right aspect ratio
        double convert =  convertX > convertY ? convertY : convertX;
        // min = 0, convert to interval <0: infinity> and multiply by convert,
        for (int j = 0; j < points.length; j++) {
            double transX = (points[j].x - min.x) * convert;
            double transY = height - (points[j].y - min.y)  * convert;
            transPoints[j] = new Point2D.Double(transX, transY);
        }

        this.polygon = new Path2D.Double();
        this.polygon.moveTo(transBody[0].x, transBody[0].y);
        for (int i = 1; i < body.length; i++) 
            this.polygon.lineTo(transPoints[i].x, transPoints[i].y);
        this.polygon.closePath();
    }

    private void drawKraj(Graphics2D g2, int width, int height) {       

        g2.setStroke(new BasicStroke(2));
        g2.fill(polygon);
        // vykreslime obrys
        g2.setColor(Color.black);
        g2.draw(polygon);
    }

    public void draw(Graphics2D g2,
            int contextWidth, int contextHeight) 
    {
        // fit to window size
        int sirkaSOdsazenim = contextWidth;
        int vyskaSOdsazenim = contextHeight;

        this.transformujToWindow(sirkaSOdsazenim, vyskaSOdsazenim);

        this.drawKraj(g2, sirkaSOdsazenim, vyskaSOdsazenim);

    }


    /**
     * Set min and max
     */
    private void zjistiLimity() {
        max = new Point2D.Double(-Double.MAX_VALUE, -Double.MAX_VALUE);
        min = new Point2D.Double(Double.MAX_VALUE, Double.MAX_VALUE);
        for(int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < body.length; i++) 
            {
                if (points[i].getX() < min.getX()) min.x = points[i].getX();
                if (points[i].getY() < min.getY()) min.y = points[i].getY();
                if (points[i].getX() > max.getX())max.x = points[i].getX();
                if (points[i].getY() > max.getY()) max.y = points[i].getY();
            }
        }
    }
```

With this code I can draw polygon, which fit to window. But I need to draw all polygons to fit to window (calculate coordinates to create this map):

[image: Final image]

What I need to edit or add? Thanks for all answers.

Answer (score 2):

You can translate the entire polygon by using:

```
g2.translate(x, y); 
g2.draw(polygon);
g2.translate(-x, -y)
```

Determining the appropriate x/y translation for each polygon is something you will need to do.

Comment: In this case, I'll have to translate every polygon by different count of pixels. I thought about this way, but I think that it's unnecessarily difficult. Especially when I have right coordinates and I only need to transform it in right way.

Comment: It is the same approach as the other answer. Yes you need to determine the origin for each polygon. The difference is you don't need to create a new polygon once you calculate the origin. You just paint the original polygon using a translation. Less work involved.

Answer (score 1):

> I need to draw a several polygons. I can draw each polygon alone, but I can't draw all polygons in the right position.

If you can draw each polygon alone, then your polygons are correct.

You need to add an origin point to your `Kraj` class. Then your `draw` method would transform the polygon points from the polygon origin to the map origin.  Assuming your polygon origin is (10,10) and a particular polygon needs to be drawn at (20,30), then you would add 10 to the x and add 20 to the y of each point in the polygon before you draw it.

You can do this my making a copy of the polygon in the draw routine before you adjust the X and Y values of each point.

Edited to add:  Here's your own code modified to transform the origin.  I've not tested these changes.

```
private void transformToWindow(Point2D windowOrigin, int width, int height) 
{
    // convert to window
    double convertX = width / (max.x - min.x);
    double convertY = height / (max.y - min.y);

    // calculate polygon to fit in window with right aspect ratio
    double convert =  convertX > convertY ? convertY : convertX;
    // min = 0, convert to interval <0: infinity> and multiply by convert,
    for (int j = 0; j < points.length; j++) {
        double transX = (points[j].x - min.x) * convert;
        double transY = height - (points[j].y - min.y)  * convert;
        transPoints[j] = new Point2D.Double(transX, transY);
    }

    this.polygon = new Path2D.Double();
    double xShift = windowOrigin.x - transBody[0].x;
    double yShift = windowOrigin.y - transBody[0].y;
    this.polygon.moveTo(windowOrigin.x, windowOrigin.y);
    for (int i = 1; i < body.length; i++) 
        this.polygon.lineTo(transPoints[i].x + xShift, 
            transPoints[i].y + yShift);
    this.polygon.closePath();
}
```

Comment: I propably understand to your point, but I'm not sure how can I write it. Can you give me a little more clue please?

Comment: @Sk1X1: See my revised answer.

Comment: Thanks. And what exactly is windowsOrigin?

Comment: @Sk1X1: The origin point of the polygon in the window, which has to be passed to your Kraj class.

Comment: I get it. But I have to calculate the origin for each polygon, right? I hoped, that exist better solution than calculate shift of each polygon separately. But thanks.

Comment: @Sk1X1: Yes, you have to calculate the origin of each of your polygons.  You can put all of these origins in a separate class if you want.